# Ubuntu Touch mistakes swipes for taps

Tags: ubuntu-touch, touchscreen, nexus-4

I'm running Ubuntu Touch OTA 13 on my Nexus 4 and i'm having a problem: Sometimes, the phone mistakes swiping or scrolling for taps. It's a real problem, because this way i can't scroll down the apps scope without launching apps.

Is that a problem with Ubuntu Touch that i should file a bug report on? Or Is it a problem with my phones hardware?

Comment: Well you might as well file a bug report. If it's reproducible, it'll get fixed. If it isn't, you may want to look into replacements options. If you have a screen protector, take that off. Try scrolling over the same screen area in apps.

Comment: I also have a Nexus 4 running OTA 13, and I have no such issue. You may want to make sure that it's not an issue with your touch screen before filing a bug report.

Comment: Yeah, i think there's something wrong with this device. I will send it back. Thanks!

Comment: It does sound like it is the device itself. On saying that have you updated to the latest version? If you fill out a bug report, you may find that more people reply to that and confirm they have the issue too.

Comment: No, it's definitely the device. I flashed it with android and it had the same quirks. Yes, I'm on the latest version, the steaming new OTA 14. I Did not send the device back though, i can live with it since it's not my daily driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no known Issue with Ubuntu Touch that can cause this.

I flashed the device with android and it had the same problems, so it is not related to the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Update your phone to the latest version that was released over the weekend. Before installing this update mine had the odd issue, mainly when trying to swipe the unity bar and across apps. However, since the upgrade I have had no issues and all seems better. Worth a shot if you have not done the upgrade already.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But as i wrote, i'm running the latest version and i have the same issue with android, so it is a hardware problem.